# Unable to launch Xcode 13 beta 1 and/or 2 on macOS Big Sur 11.4

Tags: xcode, macos-big-sur, beta, xcode13

I'm trying to install Xcode 13 beta on my MacBook Pro with macOS Big Sur 11.4. Here's what I did so far:

1. I downloaded Xcode 13 beta 2 from https://developer.apple.com/download/
2. Double click on the file, and then moved Xcode-beta.app to Macintosh HD/Applications
3. Tried to open it, but I get an error that says:

   Unable to open Xcode-beta.app due to a problem.

   Check with the developer to make sure Xcode-beta.app works with this version of macOS. You may need to reinstall the application. Make sure you install all available updates for the application and for macOS.
   Click Report to view more detailed information and send a report to Apple.

And when I click to get more info I get this:

```
Process:               Xcode [2153]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               13.0 (19161.15)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [2153]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-06-28 09:23:54.342 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 11.4 (20F71)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     5.4 (18P4663)
Anonymous UUID:        BF2F0872-D13E-DC73-9E8D-911CD7D080B3

Sleep/Wake UUID:       9EB93895-E33C-4EA2-96CD-FF88026D93E8

Time Awake Since Boot: 23000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       4800 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  dyld: Using shared cache: 4A889CE9-8D7E-304E-A5F7-84D819B0BF9C
Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:

//Here there's an infinite list of binary images such as: 
       0x10c13f000 -        0x10c142fff  com.apple.dt.Xcode (13.0 - 19161.15) <D505A1C0-5E95-3233-AB86-65959A8DE250> /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

I don't know how to solve this. I've seen other people that had a problem with antiviruses that blocked the app, but I don't have any installed. Many solutions I've seen require Xcode to be launched and set some preferences in the app's settings, but I can't launch Xcode so I can't try these solutions. I tried all the following commands:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
xcode-select --install
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

I tried all this with Xcode 13 beta 1 and beta 2, I tried deleting them and re-downloading them and trying everything again, but nothing seems to work. Is there anyone that knows how can I make it work?

Comment: "sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Develop" Makes no sense. This is Xcode-beta, not Xcode.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant to write Xcode-beta, I made copy paste from the reply of a user instead of the one I used on the Terminal. I edited the question to the correct command line